# Assign item in a group and set a behavior for each group

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm on a project with a listview, this listview has 2 groups. I'm curious to know if it's possible to create a behavior for each group.

I have an item named "Online" and an other named "Offline". These items have a red or black circle (an image) in front of them. Both items are in a group named "live" or "offline".

[image: Sample screenshot]

I want to do 2 things:

- I should be able to change an item's group whenever I want.
- When an item is in a group, the behavior should change. (For example, if the "Offline item is in the group "Live", the image will be changed to a red dot instead of a black dot)

  ```
  ImageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.bullet_black)
  ImageList.Images.Add(My.Resources.bullet_red)
  Liste.LargeImageList = ImageList

  Dim groupeOffline As New ListViewGroup("Offline")
  Dim groupeLive As New ListViewGroup("Live")
  Liste.Groups.AddRange({groupeLive, groupeOffline})

  Liste.Items.Add("Offline", 0).Group = groupeOffline
  Liste.Items.Add("Online", 1).Group = groupeLive
  ```

In my ImageView, the 0 index is the black dot
and the 1 index is the red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already includes most of what is required. You can rely on a function taking care of the modifications you want when adding new items. For example:

```
Private Sub updateGroups(curItem As String, targetGroup As String)

    Dim curIndex As Integer = 1 'Same index for both group and image
    Dim curGroup = groupeLive
    If (targetGroup.ToLower() = "offline") Then
        curIndex = 0
        curGroup = groupeOffline
    End If

    Liste.Items.Add(curItem, curIndex).Group = curGroup

End Sub
```

And you can call it like this:
`updateGroups("new live item", "Live")` or `updateGroups("new offline item", "Offline")`

Bear in mind that it expects both groups to be declared globally (you might prefer to change it such that they are passed as arguments).

Comment: Hi varocarbas, it works pretty well but i did a better version (for my project :p)
If you're intrested:
http://pastebin.com/awsEEpHt
thanks.

Comment: @Riptide With a better version, you mean taking mine and adding a try...catch? LOL. I guess that you will award this as the right answer.

Comment: I mean i use a bool to  set the group, i delete the old item in the old group and i added "If curItem = "" Then Exit Sub" because i had an issue :)
yeah so thx helping me.

Comment: @Riptide I saw your code, I know what you did (was just kidding -> the LOL thing). In any case, what you should understand is that doing that (adapting or improving the code provided by the answerer) is something you should do in any case (and thus it is not even comment-worthy). Ideally, I shouldn't write any code, just give some indications helping you to actually write the code. The reason why I write codes is because this is the quickest & most efficient way to explain the point. You should take this fact as it is (a way to explain things properly).